# iOS Location Manager and sequential processing

Tags: ios, asynchronous, cllocationmanager, synchronous, sequential

I have a LocationManager in a viewController from where I want to listen for significant changes in user's location. Then, when *locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:* triggered, I perform some data processing by calling a custom object that is a private property of the same viewController and is always the same object:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
       fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
   if (dataProcessor == nil) {
    dataProcessor = [[DataProcessor alloc] initWithDefaultValues];
   }

   [dataProcessor processData:someData];
}
```

The method called by the *dataProcessor*, in turn, later makes calls to another self methods, and the whole processing performed by this *dataProcessor* may have not finished before *locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:* is reached again and then another *[dataProcessor processData:someData]* call is made.

My question is, what is supposed to be the behavior in this situation? Being the same object called, is the second call queued till the first one has finished? Or could the second call be executed between the call of the different methods called from the first *processData* call? I don't know how to see and debug this in Xcode. I need to ensure that data processing is performed and completed in the order in which new locations are notified by the Location Manager. I am not currently making use of any thread I've created, nor GCD queues, nor semaphores, because I am not sure what is really happening there and I don't know if I need any of those features.

Thanks a lot

Comment: So, aren't `CLLocationManagerDelegate` callbacks on the same thread usually? Then how are you in the situation where you are getting additional callbacks before `processData:` returns? Have you created multiple `CLLocationManager`s on different threads? Are you sure you're not parallelizing the work of `processData:` in some way?

Comment: My LocationManager is another private property in the viewController, being the viewController the delegate itself, and I initialize LocationManager and start listening in the viewController's "viewDidLoad" method, so I assume the callback is always on the same main thread, if I don´t have misunderstood...

Comment: So, are you actually seeing `processData` running on two different threads? I can't quite tell. Maybe I'm missing the point of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`processData` method will be executed as a serial queue, because it's executed on a main thread.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: Even if "processData" triggers subsequent method calls? 
Is there any way in Xcode to see threads and call stacks at runtime, without enabling breakpoints in code?

Comment: Subsequent method calls will be executed after in FIFO order.
I can't answer about Xcode — probably there is tool for that in Instruments

Comment: So, let's say that the method "processData" calls a second method "anotherMethod". If "processData" is called a second time before the first one has completed, could you get this queue: processData (1st call) - processData (2nd call) - anotherMethod (1st call) - anotherMethod (2nd call)? Or it will be: processData (1st call) - anotherMethod (1st call) - processData (2nd call) - anotherMethod (2nd call)?